# Computed property doesn't update upon changing data variable

Tags: vue.js, computed-properties

I have a data variable named `monRaw` that is a `Moment` object representing the first day of current week:

```
...
data() {
  return {
    monRaw: moment().startOf('isoWeek')
  }
},
...
```

Then I have a computed property named `weekTitle` that displays it along with some text (it does more than that in my project, but I simplified it here):

```
...
computed: {
  weekTitle: function() {
    alert('updating computed property...');
    return `Current week starting on ${this.monRaw.format('DD')}`;
  }
},
...
```

Finally, a method named `viewNextWeek()` changes my data variable to the following week's first day:

```
...
methods: {
  viewNextWeek: function() {
    this.monRaw = this.monRaw.add(1, 'weeks');
  },
...
```

In my template, I display my computed property along with a button triggering my method:

```
{{ weekTitle }}
<button @click="viewNextWeek">Next Week</button>
```

For some reason though, my computed property does NOT get updated when I change the data variable it's based on.

It doesn't even try to: my `alert()` gets triggered on page load only, not any more after that when clicking the button.

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Moment.add` mutates the moment variable, so you are just assigning the same object back to itself, which results in no change.

Per [the docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/):

> If you want to create a copy and manipulate it, you should use
>   moment#clone before manipulating the moment.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    monRaw: moment().startOf('isoWeek')
  },
  computed: {
    weekTitle: function() {
      alert('updating computed property...');
      return `Current week starting on ${this.monRaw.format('DD')}`;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    viewNextWeek: function() {
      const newValue = this.monRaw.clone().add(1, 'weeks');

      this.monRaw = newValue;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  {{ weekTitle }}
  <button @click="viewNextWeek">Next Week</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I understand but not completely! The expression `this.monRaw.add(1, 'weeks');` changes the value of `this.monRay`, right? Then I assign this new value to `this.monRaw`, which I now understand is useless (and as you say it's assigning an object to itself). But still: `this.monRaw` should receive the NEW value not the old one isn't it?

Comment: It does not change the value of `this.monRaw`. Its value is the same object (as identified by its address in memory) as before. Its _contents_ change, but reactivity does not detect content changes like that.